# Prove it's impossible to express $P(A|B\cap C)$ through $P(A|B), P(A|C), P(B)$ and $P(C)$

Tags: probability

The original question is to express $P(A|B\cap C)$ through $P(A|B), P(A|C), P(B)$ and $P(C)$ or to prove it's not possible to do so. I am fairly certain that this isn't possible, however, I do not know how to approach this proof.

Comment: To show it's not possible you need to give examples of $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2,C_1,C_2$ such that $P(A_1|B_1)=P(A_2|B_2)$, and similarly for $P(A|C), P(B)$ and $P(C)$, but $P(A|B_1\cap C_1)\ne P(A_2|B_2\cap C_2)$..

Comment: If you take $A = \emptyset$ and $B,C \neq \emptyset$, then you can write $P(A|B \cap C) = P(A|B)P(A|C)P(B)P(C) = 0$. So it cannot be false for all $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is juts a matter of grinding through some examples. A Venn diagram is helpful.

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ with uniform probability.

Scenario 1: Let $A = \{2\}, B = \{1,2,3\}, C = \{2,3,4\}$.

Scenario 2: Let $A = \{2\}, B = \{1,2,4\}, C = \{1,2,4\}$.

Then
$PB = PC = {3 \over 4}$, $P(A \cap B) = P(A\cap C) = {1 \over 4}$ in both scenarios (and so $P(A|B) = P(A|C) = {1 \over 3}$).

In Scenario 1,  $P(A|B\cap C) = {1 \over 2}$, in Scenario 2, $P(A|B\cap C) = {1 \over 3}$.